# Formatting multiple string into one string

Tags: android, string, string-formatting

So my requirement is as follows:
I've multiple strings stored in different string variables, lot of them are hardcore string, some of them are user inputs, while some are values from database(online as well as offline database.)
I want to combine all the strings in single String variable but I want each letter formatted differently as shown in following image.

[image: Formatted String should look something like this]

where as my normal string would be like this:

> MAIN TITLE SUBTITLE: Detail 1 Detail 2 Heading 1: User Input Data Heading 2: User Input Data.

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you require this, may I ask?

Comment: I need to send an email of collected data, for which I need to format the data so it would look good in composed email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spannable String is your solution.

Refer this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html

Also refer this
http://androidcocktail.blogspot.in/2014/03/android-spannablestring-example.html

Here is an example:

```
final SpannableString text = new SpannableString("Hello World");
text.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), text.length() - "World".length(),text.length(),
        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 4, text.length() - 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
tv.setText(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

> https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html

Please check above link for string formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Html.fromHtml()` and format the string with **HTML** like;

```
String my_string = "<h1>MAIN TITLE</h1><br /><h2>SUBTITLE</h2><br />"
                   +"Detail 1 <br /> Detail 2 <br /><br/>"
                   +"<h4>Heading 1:</h4> User input data <br/>"
                   +"<h4>Heading 2:</h4> User input data"
```

Then

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.the_id_of_your_tv);
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(my_string);
```